# Hanging workouts frequency -weights-breathing-speed

Tags: abdominals

I want to ask about abs.

- My food is ok, I eat healthy foods
- I do other workouts for abs
- I was doing abs every day
- I have little body fat (I would like to calculate it somehow. I weigh 70kg and am 1.80m tall)

Now I want to stop exercises for abs and focusing only on one exercise; I want to focus to on hanging abs workouts.

I want to increase my abs visibility. I am beginner at hanging but I have the power to lift my legs up.

My questions are:

- First, to take a bag. I will add to the bag inside weights 10kgs. I will close the bag and when I am hanging I will lift this bag with my legs. As a result, I came to this question how much should I do (day / minutes / times) is this exercise with weights good?
- Second, fast or slow or normal? I mean should I do the movements fast or slow?
- How many minutes? I have listen day only 5 minutes else you don't gain abs (true or false?)
- Breathing, when should I exhale and inhale?

Answer (score 1):

> I am a beginner at hanging but I have the power to lift my legs

If your core isn't doing the work then you aren't training your abs. If you swing your legs or swing your entire body for momentum, again your abs won't be working.

> I want to stop exercises for abs and focusing only in an exercise

You should be doing more than just hanging exercises to develop your abs. You can easily implement the hanging exercises but continue to do what you were previously doing.

If you can't properly see your abs I presume it's because you don't target and isolate them properly based off what your conceptions on hanging ab exercises are.

You need to make sure you contract, control your body and isolate your abs and not use the rest of your body to assist you.

> I have listen day only 5 minutes else you don't gain abs

This is not true, you can't gain abs with only 5 minutes a day. That's barely one exercise. If you see abs it's due to low body fat rather than actual muscle.

What you should be doing is something like this

1. Reverse Crunches 3 sets to failure
2. Hanging leg raises 3 sets to failure
3. Oblique Twists 3 sets to failure
4. Ab rollouts/Planks 3 sets to failure

When doing these make sure you focus on the abs, if it starts to get difficult don't start cheating and using other parts of your body to help. Ensure all work done is solely focused on the abdominal muscles.